# How to find a pdf file in one directory within all sub directories

Tags: batch-file

The pdf file is contained in two folders below. I want to find the pdf file from parent "pdf" folder only.

```
\\172.24.191.41\data1\Journals\WILEY_JNLS\RAW\JEMT\JEMT_23092\FPP\mrt-18-057-20180618192811\pdf\mrt-18-057.pdf

\\172.24.191.41\data1\Journals\WILEY_JNLS\RAW\JEMT\JEMT_23092\FPP\mrt-18-057-20180618192811\sup\mrt-18-057.pdf
```

Comment: What needful did you do already? :-)

Comment: Your question is currently unclear, and incomplete. The title suggests you're trying to locate a pdf file, but your question body appears to suggest that your pdf file contains two folders and you wish to isolate one of those depending on its parent directory. There are several methods of performing the task, once it it clear what that task is. In order to determine the most suitable it is necessary that you post more information. Information about your specific environment, how and by whom the batch file is to be run, where it will be located, a little information about the network location.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is unclear where you do want (to start) search exactly what.
Starting from `%BaseDir%` the following batch will output all .pdf files in a parent folder named `pdf`

```
@Echo off
Set "BaseDir=\\172.24.191.41\data1\Journals\WILEY_JNLS\RAW\JEMT\JEMT_23092\FPP\mrt-18-057-20180618192811"
For /f "delims=" %%A in ('
  Dir /B/S/A-D "%BaseDir%\*.PDF" ^| Findstr /I "\\pdf\\[^\\]*\.pdf$"
') Do Echo=%%A
```